# Accessing fields of derived class object, C++ vs Java

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

If one accesses the fields of derived class object after assignment this object to variable of base class type in java, i get the expected behaviour, meaning print field's value of the derived class . In c++ value of the field, belonging to the base class is printed.

In Java, 6 is printed as expected:

```
class Ideone
{

    static class A {
        static int a = 7;
    }
    static class B extends A {
        static int b = 6;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(((B)a).b);
    }
}
```

In C++, 7 is printed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
    int i = 7;
public:

    Base(){
        std::cout << "Constructor base" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Base(){
        std::cout << "Destructor base" << std::endl;
    }
    Base& operator=(const Base& a){
        std::cout << "Assignment base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    int j = 6;
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Base b;
    Derived p;
    cout << p.j << endl;
    b = p;
    Derived pcasted = static_cast<Derived&>(b);
    cout << pcasted.j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve in c++ similar type of behaviour (printing 6).

Comment: Java "references" are basically *pointers*, or more accurately *smart pointers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve in c++ similar type of behaviour (printing 6).

It sure is, as long as you do the same thing as you do in Java.

You must remember, that even though Java has similar syntax, it is not identical. In Java, the statement `A a = new B();` creates a **reference** of base type, bound to a derived type. `((B)a)` then casts the type of the reference down to derived.

In c++, `Base b;` is not a reference variable. Copy-assigning a derived object to this variable will copy the base-sub-object of the derived object. This language feature is known as slicing. Simply use a reference to have similar semantics to your Java code:

```
Base& b = p;
```

If you access an object of concrete type `Base`, through a `Derived&` reference, you invoke undefined behaviour.

P.S. your assignment operator does not return anything, despite the return type being non-void. Not returning has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In the C++ code, `b = p;` just [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) copied `p` to `b`, `b` is still `Base` in fact. Then `static_cast<Derived&>(b)` will fail and lead to UB.

You could use reference or pointer, letting `b` point to `Derived` in fact. Then it'll be fine to down-cast it to `Derived`.

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    Derived p;
    Base& b = p;
    cout << static_cast<Derived&>(b).j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/TTJT50290)

Answer (score 2):

Your question might be meaningful if your C++ code was even close to being equivalent to your Java code.   It is not.   Even if they were written in the same language, it is hardly surprising that two non-equivalent sections of code will produce different results.

A `main()` of the form

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    Base *b = new Derived;

    std::cout << ((Derived *)p)->j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

is (approximately) equivalent to the Java code, allowing for the fact that Java blends concepts of those things in C++ called pointers and references.   It will give you the result you expect.

As will changing the statement `std::cout << ((Derived *)p)->j << endl` to the equivalent (in C++) `std::cout << (*((Derived *)p)).j << endl` which is probably a more literal interpretation of the Java code.

Actually your `main()` function yields undefined behaviour anyway, so all bets are off.   The line

```
Derived pcasted = static_cast<Derived&>(b);
```

converts a reference to `b` into a reference to `Derived`.  Since `b` is not of type `Derived`, the assignment of `pcasted` treats `b` as if it is a `Derived` when it is not.   That gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Code differences:

- static and non static member variables
- Stack object vs heap (reference) object
- Object slicing in C++ of stack-object, and simple type cast in Java.

Literally comparing Apples with Oranges!